# Does eval() behave differently on Node.js and chrome?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, jsfuck

On NodeJS (12.10.0) I get an error if I try to `eval` some JSFuck:

```
const test = '(![]+[])[(((+!+([])))+[])]+([]+[][(![]+[])[((((!+([])+!(![])+(!![]))))+[])]+(+{}+[]+[]+{})[(((((((!+([])+!(![])+!(![])+!+([])))))))+[])]+(+{}+[]+!![]+[])[(((((((((!+[])+!(+[])+!!!(![])+!!!![])))))))+[])]+(!![]+[])[((((((+(![]))))))+[])]][([]+{})[(((((+!!!(![])))))+[])+(!(+[])+(!+[])+[])]+([]+{})[(((((((+!!([])))))))+[])]+([][[]]+[])[(((!+[]+!!!!([])+!+[]+!!([])+(!![])+!+([])))+[])]+(![]+[])[((((!+([])+!(![])+(!![]))))+[])]+([]+{})[(((((((+!!!(![])))))))+[])+(((((!+[])+!!!!([])+!!([]))))+[])]+(+{}+[]+!![]+[])[(((((((((!+[])+!(+[])+!!!(![])+!!!![])))))))+[])]+([][[]]+[])[(((((((+![]))))))+[])]+([]+{})[(((((+!!!(![])))))+[])+(!(+[])+(!+[])+[])]+(+{}+[]+!![]+[])[(((((!(+[])+!+[]+!+[]))))+[])]+(+{}+[]+[]+{})[(((((((!+([])+!(![])+!(![])+!+([])))))))+[])]+(+{}+[]+!![]+[])[(((((((((!+[])+!(+[])+!!!(![])+!!!![])))))))+[])]]((+{}+[]+!![]+[])[(((((((((!+[])+!(+[])+!!!(![])+!!!![])))))))+[])]+([]+{})[(+!(![])+[])+((((+!!!![])))+[])]+([]+{})[((((!(+[])+!+([])+!+([])+(!!!![])+!!!!([])+!+([]))))+[])]+([][[]]+[])[(((((((+![]))))))+[])]+(!![]+[])[(((+!(+[])))+[])]+(+((+!!(!![])+[])+(![]+[])[(!+([])+!(![])+(!+[])+!!!!([])+[])]+(((+(!+[])))+[])+(((((((+!!![])+(+!!![]))))))+[])+((((((+([]))))))+[])+(((+!!!([])))+[]))+[])[((((+(!+[]))))+[])]+([]+{})[((((((((!(+[])+!+([])+!(!!![])+!+[]+!!!!([])+!(+[])+(!+[]))))))))+[])]+(![]+[])[(((((((((!+[])+!(!!![]))))))))+[])]+([]+{})[(((((((+!!([])))))))+[])]+([]+{})[(((((+!!!(![])))))+[])+(!(+[])+(!+[])+[])]+(+{}+[])[((((((+!(!!![]))))))+[])]+(+{}+[]+!![]+[])[(((((!(+[])+!+[]+!+[]))))+[])]+(+((+!!(!![])+[])+(![]+[])[(!+([])+!(![])+(!+[])+!!!!([])+[])]+(((+(!+[])))+[])+(((((((+!!![])+(+!!![]))))))+[])+((((((+([]))))))+[])+(((+!!!([])))+[]))+[])[(!+[]+(!![])+!(![])+[])]+(+{}+[]+[]+{})[(((((((!+([])+!(![])+!(![])+!+([])))))))+[])]+([][[]]+[])[(((!+[]+!!!!([])+!+[]+!!([])+(!![])+!+([])))+[])])())[((((!(+[])+!!!!([])+!!(!![]))))+[])]+(+{}+[])[((((+(![]))))+[])]+(((((!+[])+!(!!![])+!+([]))))+[])';
eval(test); //ReferenceError: location is not defined
```

but on chrome 72 if I do the same thing in the console, I get `apN3`.

Comment: If you do this `global.location = "somestring";` before your code, then it will not create an error in node.js.  It is apparently relying on a global `location` property which is available in the browser and is not available in node.js by default.

Comment: @Bergi - I don't have access to the human-readable source.

Answer (score 1):

No (at least not in a way significant for your problem).

Browsers provide a global [`location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) object.

Node.js does not (because it isn't oriented around HTML documents).

Answer (score 1):

The code simplifies to

```
"a"+(""+[]["sort"]["constructor"]("return location")())["3"]+"N3"
```

which does not work if there is no [global `location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) defined.